# Key cannot be duplicate - cant run this index.html after a reboot even though it worked prior to it

Tags: html

This is my code that has been running just fine for a few weeks and now it just won't run the code anymore and throw an IllegalArgumentException and I don't know where it is coming from.

```
<html>
<head>
<title>Start Page</title>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
<style>

    button {
        background-color: #555555;
        color: white;
        padding: 3px 5px;
        margin: 20px 0;
        border: none;
        cursor: pointer;
        width: 5%;
    }
</style>
</head>

<body style="background-color:powderblue;">


<form action="/Abschlussprojekt/faces/course.xhtml">    
    <h1 align="center">Abschlussprojekt Placeholder</h1>
    <div class="container" style="text-align: center">
        <label for="uname"><b>Benutzername</b></label>
        <input type="text" placeholder="Test" name="username required/>

        <label for="psw"><b>Passwort</b></label>
        <input type="password" placeholder="********" name="password" required/>

        <button type="submit" formaction="/Abschlussprojekt/faces/course.xhtml">Login</button>
        <label>
            <input type="checkbox" checked="checked" name="remember"> Benutzerdaten Merken?
        </label>
    </div>
    <br>
    <div class="container" style="text-align: center">
        <span class="psw">Passwort vergessen? <a href="#">Ändern</a></span>
    </div>
</form> 
</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

You have syntax error missing " on name attribute

```
  <input type="text" placeholder="Test" name="username required/>
```

should be

```
   <input type="text" placeholder="Test" name="username" required/>
```